# Not able install latest mlflow server version in a docker image

Tags: docker, mlflow

```
FROM linux:17.0.3.1-oraclelinux8

# build variables.
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV MLFLOW_SERVER_HOST 0.0.0.0
ENV MLFLOW_SERVER_DEFAULT_ARTIFACT_ROOT "wasbs:/<container>@<StorageAccount>.blob.core.windows.net"
ENV AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY "<Key>"
ENV BACKEND_URI "mssql+pyodbc://<UserName>:<Password>@<ServerName>.database.windows.net:1433/<DatabaseName>?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"


#Install Python 3.11
RUN yum install -y python3.11

#update pip
RUN yum install python3-pip -y
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

# install Microsoft SQL Server requirements.
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
RUN yum remove unixODBC-utf16 unixODBC-utf16-devel
RUN yum update -y && yum update \
&& yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ gnupg unixODBC-devel

  
# Add SQL Server ODBC Driver 17 for oralcelinux8
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/8/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo \
 # && yum update \  
  && yum install -y msodbcsql17 mssql-tools \
  && echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile \
  && echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc

# Set the working directory to /
WORKDIR /

# Copy the directory contents into the container at /
COPY . /

#Install mlflow server and dependencies
RUN yum -y update
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# clean the install.
RUN yum check-update -y clean

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","./startup.sh"]
```

```
requirements.txt

mlflow==2.3.0
azure-storage-blob==12.16.0
pyodbc==4.0.39
```

I am tryin to install mlflow2.3.0 but I see the below error

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt:
#0 0.900 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mlflow==2.3.0 (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.1.0, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.6.0, 0.7.0, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.9.0, 0.9.0.1, 0.9.1, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1.dev0, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13, 1.13.1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.15.0, 1.16.0, 1.17.0, 1.18.0, 1.19.0, 1.20.0, 1.20.1, 1.20.2, 1.21.0, 1.22.0, 1.23.0, 1.23.1)
#0 0.900 ERROR: No matching distribution found for mlflow==2.3.0

I did not understand where the problem is...